# Jetty - Any way to configure order of SSL ciphers?

Tags: java, jetty, jsse

I'm trying to configure Jetty to prefer ciphers using perfect forward secrecy to those that don't support it, but while allowing those older ciphers for clients that only support them.  However, I can't figure out how to configure the order for Jetty.  Is this possible?

I've set my server's SSLContextFactory's setUseCipherSuitesOrder method to true, but don't see any equivalent of the option to set a list of ciphers in server.xml, as appears to be possible with Tomcat.  I'm using embedded Jetty 9.4.x, and currently am running Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

TLS and HTTP/2 make have strict/mandatory Cipher Suite order requirements.

Since the protocols require specific behavior, you cannot control it anymore, so Jetty doesn't offer it as an option.

While the JRE does have a `SSLParameters.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true)`, it is not possible to use this in all modern HTTP connection scenarios.

You can choose to use this Java option with Jetty at `SslContextFactory.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(boolean)`.  Be aware that newer TLS versions (1.2 and above) and HTTP/2 will override this setting to fit their own needs and requirements.

Comment: I'm currently using HTTP/1.1. However, I think I've figured out how to set the order with HTTP 1.1 - if I call sslContextFactory.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true), and also call sslContextFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites with the exact name of the ciphersuites (e.g. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) in the order I want, it is respecting the order.

Is there a list of the HTTP/2 cipher order to evaluate before migrating?  (Also should I submit my HTTP 1.1 method as an answer?)